# Check if both characters are vowels or consonant and say yes, if they are different say no. Display vowels and consonants

Tags: c++

I need to write a program where I enter 2 letters and it should display "Yes" if both letters are vowels or consonants. If they are different types it should display "NO".
At the end it should display the 2 entered vowels and consonants separately.

I've tried this code but it doesn't work for NO. Can you help me fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';

    cout << "enter first charcter: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "enter second character: " << endl;
    cin >> b;

    if ((a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u') && (b == 'a' || b == 'e' || b == 'i' || b == 'o' || b == 'u'))

    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }
    else if ((a != 'a' || a != 'e' || a != 'i' || a != 'o' || a != 'u') && (b != 'a' || b != 'e' || b != 'i' || b != 'o' || b != 'u'))

    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }

    else if ((a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u') && (b != 'a' || b != 'e' || b != 'i' || b != 'o' || b != 'u'))

    {
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    }
    else if ((a != 'a' || a != 'e' || a != 'i' || a != 'o' || a != 'u') && (b == 'a' || b == 'e' || b == 'i' || b == 'o' || b == 'u'))

    {
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you write two functions: `bool isVowel(char c);` and `bool isConsonant(char c);`.  Then it becomes very easy.

Comment: Way too much repetition. You also don't need to explicitly consider every single case. A character is a vowel or it is not, you've got that part down. If both are, or both are not, YES, otherwise NO. You don't have to explicitly check for NO cases.

Comment: I am assuming you are allowed to make assumptions in your code as well. Like, it's guaranteed that a single letter will be entered, and that it will always be lower-case.

Comment: @sweenish yes, it will be a single lower-case letter each tme. I've simplified the code, but I still don't get NO for different character types. if ((a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u') && (b == 'a' || b == 'e' || b == 'i' || b == 'o' || b == 'u'))

    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }
    else if ((a != 'a' || a != 'e' || a != 'i' || a != 'o' || a != 'u') && (b != 'a' || b != 'e' || b != 'i' || b != 'o' || b != 'u'))

    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    }

Comment: (a != 'a' || a != 'e' ) is always true

Answer (score 2):

There is one issue in your second YES case and likely every consonant check. You are using logical OR, when it should be logical AND. Your character `a` can't be `'a'` **AND** it cannot be `'e'` **AND** etc. If `a = 'e'`, it's still not the other vowels, and your big logical OR case returns true when it shouldn't.

You also repeat yourself too much. It's annoying to write, and if there is an error, like you have, it needs to be fixed in many places. Use DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and create a function that tells you if you have a vowel or not.

Then, you only need to explicitly check for just the YES cases or just the NO cases. Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool is_vowel(char c) {
  std::string vowels = "aeiou";

  return vowels.find(c) != std::string::npos;
}

int main() {
  char first;
  char second;
  std::cout << "Letter: ";
  std::cin >> first;
  std::cout << "Letter: ";
  std::cin >> second;

  bool firstIsVowel = is_vowel(first);
  bool secondIsVowel = is_vowel(second);

  if ((firstIsVowel && secondIsVowel) || (!firstIsVowel && !secondIsVowel)) {
    std::cout << "YES\n";
  } else {
    std::cout << "NO\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
Letter: a
Letter: i
YES

~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
Letter: b
Letter: c
YES

~/tmp 
❯ ./a.out 
Letter: a 
Letter: h
NO

~/tmp took 4s 
❯ ./a.out 
Letter: h
Letter: a
NO
```

Comment: You could even save more time by just making two calls to `is_vowel`, saving the results in two `bool` variables, and use the `bool` variables in the `if` statement.

Comment: Very true, and a good enough suggestion that I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make it work. Thank you guys!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    bool vowel1, vowel2;

    cout << "enter first letter: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "enter second letter: " << endl;
    cin >> b;

    vowel1 = (a == 'a' || a == 'e' || a == 'i' || a == 'o' || a == 'u');
    vowel2 = (b == 'a' || b == 'e' || b == 'i' || b == 'o' || b == 'u');

    if ((vowel1 && vowel2) || (!vowel1 && !vowel2))
    {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "NO" << endl;
    }

    if (vowel1)

    {
        cout << "vowel: " << a << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "consonant: " << a << endl;
    }
    if (vowel2)

    {
        cout << "vowel: " << b << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "consonant: " << b << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```